# Cannot load ui-router nested state page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to make `main.marketing-groups.detail` a nested state of `main.marketing-groups` however when I'm calling `$state.go('main.marketing-groups.detail');` all I am getting is the url change to .../marketing-groups/detail but the HTML persists from the parent. Put some debug console.log into the marketingGroupsDetailController but it looks like it's not loaded. Both controllers do exist in index.html and are properly loaded.

```
    .state('main.marketing-groups', {
        url: '/marketing-groups',
        views: {
            'content': {
                templateUrl: 'app/modules/marketing/groups/marketing-groups.tpl.html',
                controller: 'marketingGroupsController as vm'
            },
            'right-drawer@main': {}
        }
    })

    .state('main.marketing-groups.detail', {
        url: '/detail',
        views: {
            'content': {
                templateUrl: 'app/modules/marketing/groups/detail/marketing-groups-detail.tpl.html',
                controller: 'marketingGroupsDetailController as vm'
            },
            'right-drawer@main': {}
        }
    })
```

What might wrong with it as I'm changing the code bit by bit but nothing works. I am trying to avoid using ui-view this time.

No console.log errors either.

Comment: Why you have two views with the same name 'right-drawer@main'?

Comment: It's a side panel I want to hide on those particular states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made it work with this approach. If you've got something better, please let me know.

```
        .state('main.marketing', {
        url: '/marketing',
        views: {
            'content': {
                templateUrl: 'app/modules/marketing/marketing.tpl.html',
                controller: 'marketingController as vm'
            },
            'right-drawer@main': {}
        }
    })

    .state('main.marketing.groups', {
        url: '/groups',
        views: {
            'marketing@main.marketing': {
                templateUrl: 'app/modules/marketing/groups/marketing-groups.tpl.html',
                controller: 'marketingGroupsController as vm'
            },
            'right-drawer@main': {}
        }
    })

    .state('main.marketing.groups.detail', {
        url: '/detail',
        views: {
            'marketing@main.marketing': {
                templateUrl: 'app/modules/marketing/groups/detail/marketing-groups-detail.tpl.html',
                controller: 'marketingGroupsDetailController as vm'
            },
            'right-drawer@main': {}
        }
    })
```

marketing.tpl.html

```
<div ui-view="marketing"></div>
```